# Laravel 5.4 change password

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I am currently working on the profile page wherein the user can change its password. I created a new function `changePassword()` in the UserController

```
public function changePassword(Request $request, User $employee) {
    $validator = Validator::make($data, [
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        'password_confirmation' => 'required|string|min:6|same:password'
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        Session::flash('error', "Fill-out the form correctly. Try again!");
        return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator);
    }

    $employee->password = bcrypt($request->password);
    $employee->save();
    return view('users.show', ['employee'=>$employee]);
}
```

I created this new route in `web.php` above the resource route of the User model

```
Route::put('users/{user}', 'UserController@changePassword')->name('users.changePassword');
```

I am getting a `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` every time I click the submit button. I think the problem is the route but I am not sure. Is there a Laravel functionality aside the one that sends email, because I want the users to change its password without using email. Thanks!

Here is my form

```
{!! Form::model($employee, ['method'=>'PUT', 'route'=>['users.changePassword', $employee]]) !!}
```

Comment: You need to first find the user which you want to update the password! I mean which user is updating his/her password!

Comment: You can use: `$id = \Auth::user()->id;      $employee = User::find($id);`  With this you can get the user who want to update their password and this is works as you want! Place this code above the line of `$employee->password = bcrypt($request->password);` Let me know if this works??!

Comment: I thinks it's redundant since, I am passing the object that I am updating, there is no need for me to find it. Anyway thanks, I already solved the problem by creating a new controller for just the update controller (which works but maybe unconventional)

Comment: Ok, thanks for your reply! :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of put, use post in your route as below.

```
Route::post('users/{user}', 'UserController@changePassword')->name('users.changePassword');
```

And in your form have you passed the "_method" & CSRF token (CSRF is not required, if you have disabled it, but I recommend to use it always)?

If you are using Form and HTML class (ServiceProviders) for creating HTML & Forms in blades, use as below.

```
{!! Form::model($employee, ['method' => 'POST','route' => ['users.changePassword']]) !!}

--- Your Fields Code will go here ----

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: it did not work, I think because it is a POST method, it creates a new model instead of updating an existing model

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `PUT` http verb in your form field. If you are using laravelcollective:

```
{!! Form::model($employee, ['method' => 'put','route' => 
['users.changePassword']]) !!}

--- Your Fields Code will go here ----

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Or

```
<form action="your-url" method="POST">

 {{ method_field('PUT') }}

</form>
```

Comment: i tried, it still did not work, what I did was to create an UpdatePasswordController which updates the password of the current authenticated user using Hash

Comment: just add `method_field('put')` after `csrf_field()` in your form

Answer (score 0):

Do you set parameter for route?

```
{!! Form::Model($user, ['action' => ['UserController@changePassword', $user->id],'method' => 'PUT']) !!}

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this....

this code work in my project using laravel 5.3

ubahprofilecontroller.php

```
public function updatePwd($id, Request $request)
       {
         //cek password lama
           $messages = array(
               'password_lama.required'=>'Harap masukkan password',
               'password_baru.required' => 'Password baru tidak boleh kosong',
               'ulangi_password.required' => 'Harap ketikkan ulang password baru',
               'ulangi_password.same' => 'Password baru dan konfirmasi password tidak cocok'
           );

           $rules = array (
             'password_lama'=> 'required',
             'password_baru'=> 'required',
             'ulangi_password'=> 'required|same:password_baru'
           );
           $validator = Validator::make ( Input::all (), $rules, $messages );

           if($validator->fails())
             {
                 /*return Redirect('edit_password')
                     ->withErrors($validator);*/
                     $password ='password';
                     return redirect('ubahPwd')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
             }
           else
             {
               $check = User::where('id',$id)->first();
               if (Input::get('password_lama') == $check->value)
               {
                       if(Input::get('password_baru') == Input::get('ulangi_password'))
                         {
                           $check -> password = bcrypt(Input::get('password_baru'));
                           $check -> salt_password = Input::get('password_baru');
                           // save our duck
                           $check->save();

                             /*$msg = array('msg' => 'Password changed Successfully');*/
                             return redirect('ubahPwd')->with('success','Password berhasil diubah');
                         }
                         else
                         {
                             /*$msg = array('msg' => 'New password and Confirm password did not match');*/
                             return redirect('ubahPwd')->with('salah','Password baru dan konfirmasi password tidak sama');
                         }
               }
               else
               {
                 /*$msg = array('msg' => 'Current password is incorrect');*/
                 /*return Redirect('edit_password')
                               ->with('status-failed', 'Current password is incorrect');*/
                    return redirect('ubahPwd')->with('salah','Password lama salah');
               }
             }
      }
```

profile.blade.php

```
 <form class="form-horizontal" action="{{ url('/ubahPassword/update',Auth::user()->id )}}" method="POST">
              <<div class="content" style="padding-left:50px;padding-right:50px">

                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                  <label for="id" class="col-sm-3 control-label">ID</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="id"  name="id" value="{{ Auth::user()->id }}" readonly>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="username" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Password Lama</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="username" name="password_lama">
                    @if ($errors->has('password_lama')) <p class="help-block" style="color:red;">{{ $errors->first('password_lama') }}</p> @endif
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Password baru</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="email" name="password_baru">
                    @if ($errors->has('password_baru')) <p class="help-block" style="color:red;">{{ $errors->first('password_baru') }}</p> @endif
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Ulangi Password</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="email" name="ulangi_password">
                    @if ($errors->has('ulangi_password')) <p class="help-block" style="color:red;">{{ $errors->first('ulangi_password') }}</p> @endif
                  </div>
                </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right col-sm-3">Simpan</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
```

i hope my answer helping you....